# Rails applying join but getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

hello I am new to rails  I was trying to apply joins .I have two table retailers and request .In both the table I have a column common which is 'retailer_Code'. So I want to fetch where both the column data matches .

```
        @retailers=Request.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN retailers on requests.retailer_code = retailers.retailer_code ").select(:status,:created_at,:shop_name,:request_type)
```

This is my query and getting empty response in @retailers

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :retailers
end
```

```
class Retailers < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :request
end
```

Comment: Please paste your Retailer and Request model association code.

Answer (score -1):

Through Association it is allowed to mention foreign key explicitly. In your case it's :foreign_key => "retailer_Code"

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :retailers, :foreign_key => "retailer_Code"
end

class Retailers < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :request, :foreign_key => "retailer_Code"
end
```

Comment: I don't want a foreign key I have even specified in my question .

Comment: retailer_code column I have in my both of the tables